# Update expiration time of a google push notification channel

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, push-notification, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am currently developing a web API where I need to listen for Google Calendar updates.  I have therefor implemented the google push notifications for PHP following the documentation and everything works fine ([Receiving notifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push#renewing-notification-channels)).

The problem I have is that I would like to update the channel expiration time so I don't have to create a new one every time. That is a waste of GPU and API requests, because as the documentation indicates, every time you create a new channel you start with a full initial sync ([Synchronize Resources Efficiently](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/sync)) .

Instead, I would like to always make incremental synchronization. Any ideas on how to update the  "expiration" field ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

You cannot update the channel expiration time, you have to create a new one.

#### Reference:

From the link you provided, [Renewing notification channels](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push#renewing-notification-channels):

> Currently there is no automatic way to renew a notification channel. When a channel is close to its expiration, you must create a new one by calling the **`watch`** method.

#### Related:

- [Provide a mechanism to renew activities.watch instead of erroring on non-unique channels](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186391215)